# Android OnlocationChanged stops getting called

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

When the program is running in the foreground, it works fine. Only when certain other apps are running in the foreground, and my program is running in the background, onlocationchanged stops getting called.

This will not occur immediately, but still relatively quickly after switching the app into the background. Say, within a few seconds to maybe up to a few minutes.

Now when the onlocationchanged function stops being called, it will be called again when the application holding the onlocationchanged code is switched back to the foreground.

The only code I have is in the oncreate method and in the onlocationchanged method. Other methods suchs as onresume, onpause, onproviderdisabled, onproviderenabled only contain one line that logs that a call was made. None of these functions are called when the onlocationchanged function stops being called.

This is the code I used to create to a locationmanager object:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: i'm experiencing this too. As long as the screen is on and the app is in the foreground it runs just smoothly. But as soon as something else comes to front or i turn the screen of, it will stop getting called after a couple of minutes up to two hours. >>Even with an active wakelock<<, which gets never released (which i've done only for testing purposes. I'm not putting that no release wakelock into the store...). After turning the device on again, without going into the app, but i.e. using the browser, it starts getting called again. Did you find a solution so far?

Comment: Android kills the entire process when it is running out of memory and the process is in the background.  When you switch back to the process it will appear as if nothing has happened because everything is reloaded again. To prevent android from killing code that needs to keep on running no matter what, you need to make that code into a 'service'. See [activity life cycle](http://android.okhelp.cz/wp-content/uploads/lifecycle-activity-android.png) and [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: I think you are removing the location updates in your Activity's `onPause()` or `onStop()` method. Check where have you placed this line `removeLocationUpdates()` in your Activity code.

Comment: Did you solved this @user2180253? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late in answering, but I found the solution when I encountered the same problem.

your solution here:
[Background location access checklist](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#checklist)

```
If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, also check for the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. Verify that your app has a feature that requires it.
```